# how to find substrings at the start of a main string when match does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to search for one string at the beginning of another in Python 3.x

so I have

```
for pattern, responses in substrings:
    match = re.match(pattern, statement)
    if match: # etc.
```

But
if one of substrings is `'no'` this will be found not only if the first word is 'no' but also if it is `'noggin'` for example

How can I search for the `'no'` at the start only if the word is `'no'`?

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some actual Python code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Could you search for `'no '`?

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid regex and use `if statement.startswith('no '):`?

Answer (score 2):

You need a regex [word boundary anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `\b`, which matches the boundary between word characters and non-word characters.

Try `^no\b`

See [my regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/aAlx2k/1)

Answer (score 0):

'^no$'...this regular expression should work. re.match('^no.*',string)

import re
mat=re.match('^no.*', 'no')
print(mat)

Out:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='no'>

Comment: Could you provide some verifiable code for your solution?

Comment: import re
mat=re.match('^no$', 'no')
print(mat)

Out(matching):
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='no'>

Comment: `no` isn't necessarily the whole string. A string needs to match if it begins with the "word" no, but not if it's really a word that starts with those two letters.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for `'no '` - it won't find the `no` in `noggin` because there is no space after it:

```
for pattern, responses in substrings:
    match = re.match(pattern+' ', statement)
    if match: # etc.
```

Comment: That doesn't account for other word endings: end of string, quotes, parens, commas, etc.

Comment: That is true. You can search through different endings you can think of, but it is a flaw.